# Undo action names for Core Data changes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data, nsundomanager

I'm looking for a built-in (or easy-to-implement) way to get Core Data undo/redo action names to read like "Undo edit First Name", rather than simply "Undo" or "Redo" as they do by default.

I have a Core Data application, and am using its `NSUndoManager` as my window's undo manager. It works great, but when a user makes a change to a field (inline from an `NSTableView`), the Undo menu item's title doesn't reflect which field changed.

Initial searching led me to the same question posted on [Apple Mailing Lists](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2007/Jan/msg01137.html) in January 2007. The only answer ever posted responds with *"Search for 'Model.strings' in the Core Data Programming Guide."* I didn't have a Strings file for my Model, so I created one (localized in my en.lproj directory and with UTF-16 encoding), but this made no difference.

I followed instructions from Apple's [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial/06_CustomisingErrors/errors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002834-SW3) (adapted slightly since my app is not Document-based), and the [Core Data documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005190-SW13), but my menu titles still read "Undo" and "Redo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NSManagedObject subclass add

```
-(void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSUndoManager * aUM = [[self managedObjectContext] undoManager];
    [super setValue:value forKey:key];
    if ([aUM isUndoRegistrationEnabled])
        [aUM setActionName:NSLocalizedString(key,nil)];
}
```

Comment: The `NSLocalizedString` call in your sample won't work though, since that won't look up against the Model.strings file. How would you look up a field's localized name at runtime?

Comment: I posted the above as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5790296/105717

Comment: I also modified your `if` statement accordingly: `if ([aUM isUndoRegistrationEnabled] && ![aUM isUndoing] && ![aUM isRedoing])` to avoid duplicate entries every time an undo or redo is performed.