# Localized Core Data names

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data, localization

Given the name of a Property attribute of an `NSManagedObject` and a Model.strings file in the application bundle, how do you retrieve the property's localized name?

**Additional Details:**
When I try to access the localizationDictionary, as below, that object is nil. I'm in Snow Leopard, so the documentation's warning that it may return nil until used should not apply.

```
NSString *localized = [[managedObjectModel localizationDictionary]
                       objectForKey:@"Property/thePropertyName"];
```

**Update 2/25/2012 (almost a year later)**

I think this turned out to be a bug in Snow Leopard (or at least that particular version). Now, a year later and running Lion, the code above works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you shared tells you how to access the localized property name:

```
NSString *localizedPropertyName = [[managedObjectModel localizationDictionary] objectForKey:@"Property/thePropertyName"];
```

Comment: Heh, I completely forgot you could localize the property names.

Comment: Forgive me being a bit dense today.. How would you build the localizationDictionary? I have an app that will support several languages.. Could you please provide an example say, I have a PeopleEntity, and I want to localize the name attribute.. Many thanks..